# ANGULAR runtime add service to module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

How can i add a service to the module/angular app at runtime.

Will `$injector` or `$provide` help me?

Something like

```
app.addService('s',['k',function(k){console.log('new Service k');}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `$provide` will do it. See the documentation at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide

So you could do something like this (from within `foo`):

```
app.factory('foo',functon() {
   $provide.factory('s',function() {
      console.log("new service 's'");
   });
});
```

The problem is that you cannot inject `$provide` directly into the service, so you need to capture it at module creation time.

The question is, why would you want to do this? Since the service 's' isn't declared until 'foo' is run, you run the risk of calling the service as a dependency at some other point. If it is anywhere within a normal injection, you would probably get some weird error.

Matter of fact, I think the *only* way it would work is by using the `$injector` to get it from within some other service.

So, yes, you could do it, but would you really want to?

Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ch8vu4ng/1/